# wordpress shortcode not working

Tags: customization, shortcode, woocommerce-offtopic

Hi I had created a custom billing field shipping tracking code to add shipping tracking number to the order in the backend and send this info by woocommerce order email to customer automatically returning this value as short code in html. But it doesnt work. What is wrong? Please help.

```
    /**
     * Add Shortcode 
     */
    function tracking_shortcode( ) {
       $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
       $shipping_tracking_code = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_tracking_code', true );
       ob_start();
          return $shipping_tracking_code;
       return ob_get_clean();
    }
    add_shortcode( 'tracking_code', 'tracking_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Where is `$order_id` coming from? It's never set. Also, `return ob_get_clean();` is never executed because you already return `$shipping_tracking_code` on the line above it.

Answer (score 1):

**Point-1:** it's not clear where you are getting `$order_id` from. I'm assuming it's in the `Shortcode`.

**Point-2:** You don't need to. use `ob_*` functions for returning `Shortcode` replacement content, simply returning is enough.

Assuming other parts of your CODE is correct, below is the possible CODE that should work:

1. If the shortcode is implemented in theme's `functions.php` file:

   ```
   /**
    * Add Shortcode 
    */
   function tracking_shortcode( $attrs ) {
       $attrs = shortcode_atts( array(
           'order_id' => ''
       ), $attrs );
       if( empty( $attrs['order_id'] ) ) return '';

       $order = new WC_Order( $attrs['order_id'] );
       // I've followed your code, but may be even the above line is not needed.
       // may be you can just use $attrs['order_id'] directly to get tracking code
       return get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_tracking_code', true );
   }
   add_shortcode( 'tracking_code', 'tracking_shortcode' );
   ```
2. If the shortcode is implemented using a plugin:

   ```
   /**
    * Add Shortcode 
    */
   function tracking_shortcode( $attrs ) {
       $attrs = shortcode_atts( array(
           'order_id' => ''
       ), $attrs );
       if( empty( $attrs['order_id'] ) ) return '';

       $order = new WC_Order( $attrs['order_id'] );
       return get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_tracking_code', true );
   }

   /**
    * Initiate Shortcode 
    */
   function tracking_shortcode_init()
   {
       add_shortcode( 'tracking_code', 'tracking_shortcode' );
   }
   add_action('init', 'tracking_shortcode_init');
   ```

Learn more about `shortcode` from [WordPress doc.](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/)

Comment: Tried first option entered the first code in the functions.php file, but still the shortcode is not working. Getting no returns in  email messages.

Comment: Tried the second option by entering the second code in the plugin file, still no result.

Comment: Cant understand why it doesnt display at all

Comment: Provide your full shortcode.

Comment: I had implemented the shortcode in my custom plugin using the second snippet. but it doesnt work, it returns only [tracking_code]. Where as I am able to get the value of $shipping_tracking_code in another snippet using the following code

Comment: `add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_tracking_code', 20);

function add_tracking_code( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
          $shipping_tracking_code = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_tracking_code', true );
 $url = 'http://my.courier/tracking';
 $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  if($order->status === 'shipped' ) {
<h3><?php _e( 'Tracking no', 'my-plugin' ); ?></h3>
<?php _e( 'Your order has been shipped. Waybill no is:', 'my-plugin' ); ?><?php echo $shipping_tracking_code; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" ><?php _e( 'Track', 'my-plugin' ); ?></a>
} 
}`

Comment: I'll check it. However, as I've said in my answer, you must make sure we are getting $order_id, either from shortcode like [tracking_code order_id="1"] or from somewhere else.